# Discard apart of a string after DOT . using excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following column value in **B4 in tab 1 i.e 2014-07-01 01:55:58.717286-05**
out of which **discard portion .717286-05** and copy only **2014-07-01 01:55:58** using excel formula to another tab on excel

The formula Im using it **=INDIRECT("tab3!B4")**
Please suggest a way to discard value that comes after a **.** like (.717286-05) 
for example out of  2014-07-01 01:55:58.717286-05 copy only 2014-07-01 01:55:58
How to achieve this using excel formula ?

Comment: Why did you use `INDIRECT`? And when I put your datetime value in excel, it automatically removes everything including and after the dot, albeit rounding up the seconds

Comment: @Jerry
could you please show me the sample

Comment: I don't know what more to show than [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vZ0bL.png) because there is no formula, just copy/pasting the value. The rounding can be fixed with a formula.

Comment: Is your value in B4 in the form of text?

Comment: @L42
Yes value in B4 is in the form of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=TEXT(tab3!B4, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")
```

Comment: @ronan ah I thought you want it exactly as you describe in question. Above formula gives `2014-07-01 01:55:59` :)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have your sample value in sheet named tab3 on cell B4, use below formula:

`=LEFT(tab3!B4,SEARCH(".",tab3!B4)-1)`

Above assumes there's only one dot and returns value as text.

**Edit1:**
If you want to return it in date format:

`=ABS(LEFT(tab3!B4,SEARCH(".",tab3!B4)-1))`